# SQL: How to subtract two fields belongs to same ID

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have output as below

[image]

In the above code, Tx_ID stays same but purchase second entry became NULL. so I got multiple rows.

Now I have to calculate the time difference between first purchase and second purchase but always TX_ID stays same.

Any suggestions, greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Clue: Use Lag function if you are using sql server 2012 and above

Comment: @saravanatn, I am using Oracle DB.

Comment: What if there are more than two purchases?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have verified, each Tx_ID has participated in only two purchases or less but not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only 2 entries for each Tx_ID, you can try this:

```
SELECT Tx_ID,SUBTRACT(MAX(Tx_Time),MIN(Tx_Time)) FROM Tx_Table GROUP BY Tx_ID HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Your logic didn't work for me 100% but with the error from your solution, I have searched and got something that's working for me. for Oracle, you don't need to use SUBTRACT or DATEDIFF functions and you can subtract two dates automatically. Thank you.

Comment: @Ten-Coin glad that I could be of help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LAG](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php) to get the previous value.
Then use that to get the difference with the current record.

```
SELECT 
 t.*, 
 t.tx_time - LAG(t.tx_time) OVER (PARTITION BY t.tx_id ORDER BY t.tx_time) AS timestamp_diff 
FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Comment: this's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The following should exactly compare between 1st and 2nd time in order for a Tx_ID

```
SELECT   tx_id, 
         Subtract(Max(tx_time),Min(tx_time)) 
FROM     tx_table T1 
WHERE    tx_time >= 
         ( 
                SELECT Max(tx_time) 
                FROM   tx_table T2 
                WHERE  tx_time < 
                       ( 
                              SELECT Max(tx_time) 
                              FROM   tx_table 
                              WHERE 
                              and    tx_id = t1.tx_id) 
                AND    tx_id = t1.tx_id) 
GROUP BY tx_id 
HAVING   count(*) > 1
```